# Riemann sum for improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Suppose that $f:[0,\infty)\to[-1,1]$ is a continuous function at zero and at all but finite number of points such that $f(0)=1$ and $\int_0^\infty f^2(x)dx<\infty$. Let $\{a_n\}_{n\ge1}$ be a sequence of positive integers such that $a_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. The right Riemann sum
$$
\frac1{a_n}\sum_{j=1}^{a_n}f^2(j/a_n)
$$
converges to the integral $\int_0^1f^2(x)dx$ as $n\to\infty$. Also, for a positive integer $m$, we have that
$$
\frac1{a_n}\sum_{j=1}^{ma_n}f^2(j/a_n)\to\int_0^mf^2(x)dx\quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty.
$$
Let $\{b_n\}_{n\ge1}$ be a sequence of positive integers such that $b_n/a_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Intuitively, it seems that
$$
\frac1{a_n}\sum_{j=1}^{b_n}f^2(j/a_n)\to\int_0^\infty f^2(x)dx\quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty.
$$
Is it true? How can I show this?

References are also welcome. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you square $f.$ Why not just assume $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,1]$ continuously, and $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx < \infty?$

A counterexample given by Alex Francisco shows the answer to your question is no. I'm going to describe another answer that uses the same idea, but may be simpler.

Over each $n=2,3,\dots$ consider a thin triangle centered over $n,$ of base $1/n^2$ and height $1.$ Let $f$ be the tops of these triangles, with $f=0$ everywhere else. Then $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty),$ and

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)\, dx = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left (\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot 1\right ) <\infty.$$

However, thinking of $a_n=n, b_n = n^3,$ we have

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n^3}f(j/n) \ge \frac{1}{n}(f(2) + f(3) + \cdots +f(n^2)) = \frac{1}{n}(n^2-1) \to \infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

The last proposition is false. Define$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\sqrt{-2x + 1}; &\displaystyle  0 \leqslant x \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\\
\displaystyle \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} - \frac{2^n}{n} |x - n|}; &\displaystyle \exists n \in \mathbb{N}_+,\ |x - n| < \frac{1}{2^n}\\
0; & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$

The graph of $f^2$ is shown below.

[image]

On the one hand, $f(0) = 1$, $f$ is continuous on $[0, +\infty)$, $|f| \leqslant 1$, and$$
\int_0^\infty f^2(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{4} + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n 2^n} < +\infty.
$$

On the other hand, if $\displaystyle \frac{b_n}{a_n} \to +\infty \ (n \to \infty)$ and $b_n \geqslant a_n n^{a_n}$ holds for infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}_+$, then for these $n$,\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{a_n} \sum_{j = 1}^{b_n} f^2\left(\frac{j}{a_n}\right) &\geqslant \frac{1}{a_n} \sum_{j = 1}^{a_n n^{a_n}} f^2\left(\frac{j}{a_n}\right) \geqslant \frac{1}{a_n} \sum_{k = 1}^{n^{a_n}} f^2(k) = \frac{1}{a_n} \sum_{k = 1}^{n^{a_n}} \frac{1}{k}\\
&> \frac{1}{a_n} \int_1^{n^{a_n}} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x} = \frac{\ln n^{a_n}}{a_n} = \ln n.
\end{align*}
Therefore,$$
\varlimsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{a_n} \sum_{j = 1}^{b_n} f^2\left(\frac{j}{a_n}\right) = +\infty > \int_0^\infty f^2(x) \,\mathrm{d}x.
$$

Comment: The idea is that $b_n$ cannot grow too quickly, right? Would the last proposition in my question hold if $b_n=n$?

Comment: My proof still holds if $\frac{1}{a_n} \ln \frac{b_n}{a_n} > M$ holds for infinitely many $n$, where $M$ is a sufficiently large number. Thus, when $a_n = \ln \ln \ln n$ and $b_n = a_n \ln n$, the proposition is still false.

Comment: I guess the problem mainly arises from the fact that $f^2$ is not monotonic instead of the growing speeds of $a_n$ and $b_n$.

Comment: Nice answer (+1)! It is a minor detail, but I think the integral should be $\int_1^{n^{a_n}+1}$. I we assumed that $f^2$ is eventually nonincreasing, we would not be able to use the same counterexample. The sum would be bounded by the integral which is finite, right? Would the last proposition in my question be correct under this assumption? I should probably ask another question.

Comment: Well, $n^{a_n} + 1 > n^{a_n}$ :) And with the condition that $f^2$ is decreasing on $[x_0, +\infty)$ for some $x_0 \geqslant 0$, I think the proposition is true.